# On the relative merits of `"$@"` and `"$@[@]"`

Tags: zsh

Whenever I'm writing a script (or function) that is supposed to "pass along" its arguments to some other downstream "callable" (binary, script, function, etc.) `foo`, I code this passing along of arguments like this

```
foo "$@"
```

...but I have also seen this alternative

```
foo "$@[@]"
```

I have tried, unsuccessfully (at least with `zsh`), to concoct scenarios in which these two approaches would produce different results.

Are they really synonymous?  If not, when would one prefer one form over the other?

---

(I'm primarily interested in the case of `zsh`, which is my everyday shell, but at work I often need to write `bash` scripts, so I'd be curious about the answer to this question for `bash` as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"$@"` is a Bourne shell invention (1979). That's meant to expand to the list of positional parameters, as if you had typed `"$1" "$2" "$3"...`.

When David Korn added array support in the early 80s, it extended that concept to arrays with the `"${array[@]}"` syntax. `zsh` also supports the `"$array[@]"` shorter form.

`"$@"` refers to the positional parameters (starting from `$1`), it's a bit like an array, but except in `zsh` or `yash`, not exactly. For one, `$@` starts at index 1, while other arrays in `ksh` or `bash` start at 0. `${@[@]}` won't  work in `ksh` or `bash`.

The only shells where `"${@[@]}"` works are `zsh` and `yash`. `zsh` is the only one where `"$@[@]"` works. There's no point using it over the standard `"$@"`. What could be more useful is something like say: `"$@[1,3]"` to get the first 3 positional parameters.

If the point is that you would like to use an array-like syntax, in `zsh`, you can use `"$argv[@]"` (`$argv` is an array that refers to the positional parameters, like in `csh`/`tcsh`/`fish`).